# How to extract all content in the webpage from Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I am using `Scapy1.4` to crawl content from web pages by specifying a set of URL's. I need help on how to extract various information, i.e URL's,Title,Body from the page.

Currently, I am using the following URL

```
https://healthlibrary.epnet.com/GetContent.aspx?token=3bb6e77f-7239-4082-81fb-4aeb0064ca19&chunkiid=32905
```

And my code is

```
class gsapocSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "gsapoc" 
    start_urls =["https://healthlibrary.epnet.com/GetContent.aspx?token=3bb6e77f-7239-4082-81fb-4aeb0064ca19&chunkiid=32905"] 
    def parse(self, response):
        responseSelector = Selector(response) 
        for sel in responseSelector.xpath('//ul/li'):
            item = GsapocItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('//ul/li/a/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['body'] = sel.xpath('//body//p//text()').extract()
            #item['text'] = sel.xpath('//text()').extract()
            #body = response.xpath('//body//p//text()').extract()
            #print(body)
            yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand why set the `XPath` expression like that. There are even no `ul` elements in your page.

Since your target is just to get URL, title, and body. Here are some suggestions:

1. URL. You can get URL from `response` by `response.url`
2. Title. Depending on what kind of title you are looking for, there are two options: the `title` tag and the specified element.
3. Body. Do you want the whole page or only the text? If the former, `response.body` is okay, and if the latter, you need to specify how to extract all content.

Anyway, I think you need some knowledge of HTML and XPath.

Thanks.